# css menu active sub links to show on parent link

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu that has active links, i currently have it working but if an active link is a sub link, that particular link shows as active but if a sub link is set to active its only showing on the same link and i want it to show on its parent link

how can i achieve this?

Here is my current CSS for the active links:

```
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li a.active {
    color:#F36F25;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

currently there is an active class on Customers > View Customers

i have created a fiddle here with full code: http://jsfiddle.net/ty7x2wpj/

Comment: _“how can i achieve this?”_ – using CSS alone: Not at all; there is currently no parent selector in CSS. You need a class on the parent link as well or something like that.

Comment: there must be a way to make the parent link active if the sub link has an active class

Comment: Nope. If you need it, do it via JavaScript (which your menu is using already anyway). Find link with active class, go up to its parent item, and set a class on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using javascript to dynamically add an active class to the parent link.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#nav li:has(a.active) > a').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#nav {
    background-color:#F36F25;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
 height:35px;
 left:0;
 z-index:1;
 border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#nav>li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
 z-index:9999;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    margin:0;
    background: #F36F25;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
}
#nav li:hover > a, 
#nav li a.active{
 color:#F36F25;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border:1px solid #F36F25;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#nav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}
#nav li ul li {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background-color: #F36F25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    width:145px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color:#F36F25;
    border:1px solid #f36f25;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav" class="clearfix">
<li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/dashboard');">Dashboard</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/helpdesk/tickets');">Tickets</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('//reminders/view_reminders');">Reminders</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/reminders/addreminder');">Add Reminder</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/reminders/view_reminders');">View Reminders</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/');">Companies</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/addcustomer');">Add Customer</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/contacts/add_contact');">Add Contact</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/salesman/addsalesman');">Add Salesman</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/contracts/editcontract');">Edit Contract</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/contracts/addcontract');">Add New Contract</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/addcustomer?company_status=Prospect');">Add Prospect</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/contacts/contacts');">View Contacts</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/upload_records');">Upload Records</a></li><li><a class="active" href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/customer/viewcustomer');">View Customers</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/salesman/viewsalesman');">View Salesman</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/billing');">Billing</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/direct_debits');">Direct Debits</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/upload_voip_services');">Upload VoIP Services</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/viewinvoices');">Pending Invoices</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/daily_cdrs');">Daily CDRs</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/viewhistoricinvoices');">Historic Invoices</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/voip_unmatched_calls');">VoIP Unmatched </a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/pending_direct_debits');">Pending Direct Debits</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/upload_line_services');">Upload Line Services</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/billing/upload_hostedexchange_services');">Upload Hosted Exchange Services</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/messaging/viewemails');">Messaging</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/messaging/viewemails');">View Emails</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/messaging/send_email/send_email');">Send Email</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/messaging/sendtext');">Send Text</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/messaging/view_text_messages');">Text Messages</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/servicestatus/viewservicestatus');">Status</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/servicestatus/addservicestatus');">Add Service Status</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/servicestatus/viewservicestatus');">View Service Status</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/servicestatus/maintenance/addmaintenance');">Add Maintenance</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/servicestatus/maintenance/viewmaintenance');">View Maintenance</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/knowledgebase/editkbarticle');">Knowledgebase</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/knowledgebase/newkbarticle');">Add KB Article</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/knowledgebase/editkbarticle');">View KB Article</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/');">Pricing</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/pricing/broadband_products');">Broadband Products</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/pricing/pricelist');">Price List</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/pricing/callcosts');">Call Costs</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/settings');">Settings</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/users/users_view');">View Users</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/users/users_add');">Add User</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/signature');">Company Signature</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/users/permissions');">Permissions</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/myaccount/edit');">My Account</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/remotephonebooks');">Remote Phone Books</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/');">Reports</a><ul><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/reports/helpdesk/tickets_report');">Tickets Report</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/reports/helpdesk/customersupporthoursreport');">Check Support Hours</a></li><li><a href="#" onClick="OpenPage('/reports/billing/customerbillinglist');">Customer Billing List</a></li></ul></li><!--<li><a href="#" onclick="printSelection(document.getElementById('page_cont'));return false">Print This Page</a></li>-->
<li><a href="/login/logout.php">Logout</a></li>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li a:hover .active {
    color:#F36F25;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

No js needed